# Would a SUM query or looping through an array of objects and summing a data member be more efficient?

Tags: php, mysql

Suppose I have 50 objects in an array and each object has the property `cost`. Also, all of the objects are in a MySQL database.

Would it be more efficient to loop through all of the objects and adding up their `cost` member, or make a query such as `SELECT sum(cost) FROM ...`?

EDIT: A PDO database object has already been established.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it's far more efficient to have MySQL do it for you. However, if it really is *just* 50 objects, other factors such as network connection to the database may come into play. However, it's never a good idea to write code that assumes the application will not scale; so use MySQL :-)

Answer (score 3):

depends on array size, whether you have already established a database connection etc. I'd go for the looping part in general, since its only 50 items. however the ultimate answer is a benchmark you can do for yourself..

Answer (score 1):

SUM query.  Hands-down.  If it's not way more efficient than looping through an array in your app code, then you have some database tuning to do. :)

Answer (score 1):

Sum query. It's going to be way more efficient than you trying to do it yourself.

In any case, they are going to be similar enough that it won't matter, which would mean you would want to use sum as it is sometimes fast and sometimes about the same. No reason to risk it by executing the code yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with a table with 74601 records in php and found that, sql SUM query is approx 10 times faster than looping in php

[Check result here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGApy.png)